# Cookie is not set after redirecting from the Payment service provider

Tags: node.js, express, express-session, paytabs

We have an online shop and recently found an issue: quite often the session is lost after redirecting from the payment gateway after a successful transaction.

The shop is running on `example.com` and the gateway on `gateway.com`.

When we access `POST example.com/order` this creates an payment url on the gateway and is going to redirect there.

After the payment is done, when coming back to the `example.com/thank-you`, the `cookie` header does not have the `connect.sid` anymore, hence the session is not set anymore.

I am trying to figure out why the cookie would not be set because everything works fine except for when we access the payment gateway.

I tried to do `res.json({ url: paymentUrl })` and access the url manually. It has exactly the same issue.

What could cause `example.com` to lose the `connect.sid` cookie after the redirect from the payment gateway?

We use PayTabs as payment processing provider.

Comment: I am having a same issue with node express after successfully payment return i lost all session stored. Did you resolved this already?

Comment: @KashyapPatel I solved it by passing the session id in the return url, and requerying the session by that. I am afraid it's a bug in Chrome, even though I am not sure...